# Выборка элементов nth-child

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как задать с помощью `nth-child` допустим тегу `li` определённые стили в такой последовательности:

- 1,2 `li` должен иметь одни стили,
- 3,4 `li` другие стили.  И так далее в цикле, тегов `li` может быть много

Answer (score 5):

```css
ul li{
  color:red;
}
ul li:nth-child(4n-1),
ul li:nth-child(4n){
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
li {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

li:nth-child(4n+1), li:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Cheg, кстати нужно добавить в код большую управляемость для li, т.е. допустим для 1го и 2го li одни и теже стили, но для 1го li, нужно задать ещё свои стили, отличные от других li. Тоже самое и для остальных 3го и 4го li

Comment: подскажите, как это правильно реализовать? т.е. допустим что в теге li есть ещё параграф. И в определённой последовательности нужно чередовать стили для конкретных li и параграфов. Но чтобы повторялись через каждые 4 тега li

Comment: @word ну видимо для `li:nth-child(4n+1)` ниже прописываешь еще дополнительные стили, отличные от `li:nth-child(4n+2)` ... для 3/4 тоже ...но лучше вопрос новый задать где наглядно показать что имеется, что хочется чтоб было и как это происходит.